# Adding username to audit table

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have a web application in which a user must log into. I am using `Hibernate` to save objects to the `MySQL` database. In the database i have triggers which insert new records into audit tables when ever an insert/update/delete is done on an object

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_insert_Book` BEFORE INSERT ON Book FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN   
         INSERT INTO audit_book (AUDITTYPE,AUDITDATE,bookId, bookName, pages) VALUES ('I',NOW(), NEW.bookId, NEW.bookName, NEW.pages);
    END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see from the trigger above i am inserting a new record into the `audit_book` table when ever an insert is done on the `Book` table. The insert is done using the following code

```
public void addNewBook(Book book) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(book); 
}
```

I have a method which returns the user that is currently using the system

```
@ModelAttribute("username")
    public String getPerson(Principal principal) {
    return principal.getName();
}
```

My question is how can i pass this username to the database so that the username is added to the audit table without adding the username to the Book object?

Comment: In short, you can't.  Triggers run within the RDBMS, outside your application context (where such vital information such as application user state is kept)—that is why they are generally unsuited to generating audit logs.  Better to perform auditing within the application itself (still saved to the database if so desired), for which many tools already exist.

Comment: That said, I suppose your application could set a MySQL [user variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) at the start of each session, which is then accessed within your triggers... but that has a lot of potential to go wrong (what happens if a session is dropped, e.g. due to timeout or network error, and automatically reconnects without reestablishing the user variable state?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it that way, because the database is not aware of the logic about identifying application users.

You could consider using [Hibernate Envers](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-use-hibernate-envers-to-audit-data-including-username/) instead of database triggers for auditing purposes. In the linked example you can see how to accomplish your goal in the section *4. Add username information to each revision*.